# How to force smart contract to accept ether when deployed on Polygon chain

Tags: ethereum, polygon, solidity, nft

I have written a contract to mint NFT in solidity. I intend to deploy it to Polygon eventually.
There’s a slight confusion, I have put the price in my contract as **0.1 ether** which works fine on **Rinkeby**. When I deploy the same contract on Mumbai Polygon price value **0.1** is deducted but in **Matic** instead of **ether**. Now, this makes sense because **ether** essentially represents the default coin of a deployed chain. My requirement is to ask users to bridge their **ethers** to Polygon (just like we do for OpenSea) and then pay using **ether**. How can I force this check that incoming value is in **ether** otherwise reject transaction?

Answer (score 0):

use WETH to accept the payments instead of the coin of the chain, you should learn to interact with erc20 tokens in order to do what you need